# Black screen after first battle

Tags: pc, shadowrun-returns

I just recently pickup up this game on the Classics Return Humble Bundle and everything was going fine until I finished the first battle.

After that, I go back to the apartment and I talk some more with Sam Watts and when I say I'll go to Seattle, the screen fades to black and nothing happens.
It just stays black with the mouse cursor on.

If I press escape then the screen comes back and the in-game menu appears but then I just get stuck in the conversation with Sam with the "continue conversation" button greyed out.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**TL;DR** - Don't use backslashes `\` (on Windows) in the name of your character (or any other special character, if you want to be extra safe).

**Explanation** - After searching a bit on the internet, I ended up in the official game forums in the post where they detail how to report bugs.
There they suggested to check out the unity logs.

So I did, I opened up `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Shadowrun Returns\Shadowrun_Data\output_log.txt`.

After a bit of searching I found the following error: `IsolatedStorageException: Could not find a part of the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Shadowrun Returns\DumpBox\0309_16-53-59_J0h_\__5_\_0\_\__report.csv".`

I checked the `DumpBox` folder and confirmed that the `.csv` file didn't exist.

Essentially the game creates a `.csv` file with your character's name in the file name and if you have a backslash in it, it will fail to create and read the file.

This leads to crashing the thread responsible for loading and thus getting stuck on the black screen.

Comment: Nice debugging skills!

Comment: @vianna77 Thank you! Programming for a living comes in handy when trying to fix these things :P.

Comment: I know ;) we are both on stackoverflow.

Comment: They didn't sanitize their inputs? I hope there's no database involved or else little Bobby Tables would have a real hard time too.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks for this.  I had the exact same problem and never figured out how to fix it, except that when I returned to the game a year or two later - after buying a whole new computer - it magically worked.  I don't remember my username the first time around, but I guess I had some oddball character in there.

Comment: 1) Create a character called ../../../../../../../../../../../../windows/system32/kernel32.dll; 2) ????; 3) reinstall windows

Comment: I'm  curious as to why you had backslashes in your character name.

Comment: Great. Now I just had to join Arqade to upvote this :)

Comment: @Nzall I was going for a hacker looking name so I replaced n with `|\|` and w with `\/\/`. Plenty of backslashes there :P.